# Determining Markov Chain order from joint probability distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-chains

I understand the simple case where

> $X \to Y \to Z$ form a Markov Chain if their joint distribution is
>   $P(x,y,z) = P(x)P(y\mid x)P(z\mid y)$

However, I have trouble understanding the statement below.

> When the joint distribution $p(x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2) = p(x_1,x_2)p(y_1\mid x_1) p(y_2\mid x_2)$, $Y_1 \to X_1 \to X_2 \to Y_2$ forms a
>   Markov Chain

I can't see why Markov Chain is in that order. What am I missing?

Comment: Pure algebra: by definition, $p(y_1,x_1,x_2,y_2)=p(x_1,x_2)p(y_1\mid x_1) p(y_2\mid x_2)$ equals $$p(x_1,x_2)p(y_1, x_1)p(x_1)^{-1} p(y_2\mid x_2)=p(y_1)p(x_1\mid y_1)p(x_2\mid x_1)p(y_2\mid x_2)$$

Comment: @Did: This is a good answer, much clearer than the existing one -- it would be good to have it as an answer.

Comment: @Did, thanks for the explanation. I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

Hoping I understood the question right, you must prove that the chain you wrote is a Markov chain. Than, if you change the order (for example $Y_2$ before everything else), you may see that you don't find a Markov chain.

All you have to do is verify the Markov property at each stage. At $X_1$ it is easy. At $X_2$ you have $P(X_2 = x_2 | X_1 = x_1, Y_1 = y_1) = \frac{P(X_2 = x_2, X_1= x_1, Y_1 = y_1)}{P(X_1 = x_1, Y_1 = y_1)}$. Now you have to find the marginal probability distributions, which is easy because you have the joint probability distribution. You find that $P(X_1 = x_1, Y_1 = y_1)= p(x_1)p(y_1\mid x_1)$ and $P(X_2 = x_2, X_1= x_1, Y_1 = y_1)= p(x_1,x_2)p(y_1\mid x_1)$. So you find $P(X_2 = x_2 | X_1 = x_1, Y_1 = y_1) =  P(X_2 = x_2 | X_1 = x_1)$, which is the Markov chain property. The same you can do in every other step.

I hope this is of help.